# What does it mean for an operator to bind in Perl?

Tags: perl, binding, operators, operator-precedence

For instance, in "Programming Perl", there are sentences such as this one:

> These string operators bind as tightly as their corresponding arithmetic operators.

In other places, both in "PP" and in perldoc, the authors use phrasing such as "binds tightly"; for instance, when referring to =~, or "binds even more tightly" when referring to ** (exponentiation).

If this were the same as precedence, it would not be possible to say things like "even more tightly", I'm guessing. You'd say "higher/lower precedence" instead.

So what exactly does it mean for an operator to bind?

Comment: TLP, I mentioned specific operators for the last two instances. For the first sentence quoted, the operators were multiplication (*) and string multiplication (x). I'm confused by the choice of words to describe operator precedence (if this is what is is), hence my question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its about precedence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This refers to operator precedence. In the statement

```
a = b + c * d
```

The multiplication has higher precedence, and therefore "binds" more tightly than addition.

Operators that bind more tightly are evaluated before less-tightly bound operators.

Comment: Also thanks to the person who clarified the semantics of the verb bind for me, but later deleted the comment; and to @TLP for taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 6):

You may have a look at the [precedence list](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity) in the documentation and compare it with the texts you read. I feel pretty sure that they are talking about precedence, though.

Precedence is a form of binding, in that it "glues" arguments together with different strength. A common mistake people make, for example, is using:

```
open my $fh, "<", "input.txt" || die $!;
```

Which is a silent and deadly error, because `||` "binds more tightly"/has higher precedence than the comma `,` operator, so this expression becomes:

```
open my $fh, "<", ("input.txt" || die $!);
```

And since the string "input.txt" is always true, no matter what, since it is a constant, the `die` statement is never used. And the `open` statement can therefore fail silently, leading to hard to find errors.

(The solution is to use the lower precedence operator `or` instead of `||`, or as [mob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168657/mob) points out, override precedence by using parentheses.)

Comment: Or, since TMTOWTDI, the solution is to use parentheses.

Comment: @mob Well, this was a context related solution.